# taffy authentication using a key

Tags: authentication, coldfusion, restful-authentication, cfml, taffy

using this code for taffy authentication

```
<cfscript>
    function onTaffyRequest(verb, cfc, requestArguments, mimeExt, headers, methodMetadata, matchedURI) {
        local.status = {Status:'Forbidden'};
        local.invalidReturnData = representationOf( local.status ).withStatus(401);

        //get basic auth data, if any, and pass it into the resources
        local.credentials = getBasicAuthCredentials();
        var validateResult = validate(credentials.username, credentials.password);

        arguments.requestArguments.username = local.credentials.username;
        arguments.requestArguments.password = local.credentials.password;

        /* CATCH NO BASIC auth*/            

        if ( methodMetadata.keyExists("allow_public") && methodMetadata.allow_public == true ){
            return true;
        }
        //if username is blank return false
        else if (arguments.requestArguments.username is ""){
            return local.invalidReturnData;
        }

        //check invalid password
        else if(arguments.requestArguments.password is ""){
            return local.invalidReturnData;
        }

        else if (structKeyExists(arguments.requestArguments, "refuse") and arguments.requestArguments.refuse)
        {
            return noData().withStatus(405);
        }

        else if ( validateResult == false ) {
            return noData().withStatus(401, "Not Authorized");
        }
        else{
            return true;
        }
    }
</cfscript>
<cffunction name="validate">
    <cfargument name="username" required="true" default="">
    <cfargument name="password" required="true" default="">
    <cfquery name="local.myQuery" datasource="dsn">
        SELECT username,password FROM auth 
        WHERE username = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#arguments.username#"> 
        AND password = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#arguments.password#"> 
        AND status = 1
    </cfquery>
    <cfif local.myQuery.recordcount>
        <cfreturn true>
    <cfelse>
        <cfreturn false>
    </cfif>
</cffunction>
```

here it works where with every call, i have to provide username/password but i want to change it like using as key, and one user can have multiple keys
and if username/password do not exists, one method i want is to pass username/password and email which will generate a new signup and a key
can anyone guide

also needs to pass the auth using headers

Comment: It looks like `validateResult` isn't used until a ways down in the code. So perhaps a bit before that is where your alternate authentication happens. Some OT suggestion. Rather than `if else`through all these scenarios, just use if and return when you have reached a know state.

Comment: ok, thanks for the answer, but my goal here is to authenticate against which is specific to each user, once the key is created, i want the api should be used for authentication instead of username/password

Comment: Disclaimer the link is to code I have written

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to do something like this.

Build the token at an end point

**resources/login.cfc**

```
 ...
var loginToken = createUUID();

User[1].setLoginToken(loginToken)
    .setTokenCreateDate(now());
EntitySave(User[1]);

return rep({
    'message' : {
        'type' : 'success', 
        'content' : '<b>Success:</b> You have logged in.'
        },
    'time' : GetHttpTimeString(now()),
    'data' : loginToken
    });
 ...
```

At token gets returned here. It is up to the client application to keep the token and to return it with subsequent requests

**Application.cfc**

```
function onTaffyRequest(verb, cfc, requestArguments, mimeExt, headers, methodMetaData, matchedURI)  {
    ...
   // lesser user identification happens here

    ...

    var Login = EntityLoad("Users", { loginToken : listrest(arguments.headers.authorization, " ") }, true);

    if (isNull(Login))  {
        return rep({
            'message' : {'type'     : 'error', 'content' : '<b>Error:</b> You must provide a authorization that is valid.' },
            'time'  : GetHttpTimeString(now())
            }).withStatus(401);
    }
```

Source code: https://github.com/jmohler1970/Taffy_withUI

Disclaimer the link is to code I have written